# Filter or group a collection in Liquid

Tags: jekyll, liquid

For a simple personal Jekyll blog, I want to group my `site.posts` by an attribute on `post`, lang (language). This is either "en", "nl" or nil.

I then want to render two lists of posts. Currently I have:

```
<section lang="nl">
<h2>Nederlandse Artikelen</h2>
<ul class="posts">
  {% for post in site.posts limit:50 %}
    {% if post.lang == "nl" %}
      {% include li_for_post_with_date.yml %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
<a href="archief.html">Archief »</a>
</section>
<section lang="en">
<h2>English Articles</h2>
<ul class="posts">
  {% for post in site.posts limit:50 %}
    {% if post.lang == nil or post.lang == "en" %}
      <li><span>{{ post.date | date_to_string }}</span> &raquo; <a href="{{ BASE_PATH }}{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This has two problems:

1. Most annoying; when in the last 50 posts, there are 47 lang=en and 3 lang=nl, I now get a skewed list. I would want 25 lang=en and 25 lang=nl entries.
2. The loop is walked over twice, this strikes me as inneficient.

Is there a way to assign or prepare a collection in Liquid? That way I could loop over `site.posts` once and prepare a nested collection like `site.grouped_posts[en]`.

Or another trick?

**Solution**

As [Tom Clarkson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13586001/73673) points out, maintaining a counter is the right direction. However, incrementing a counter has only landed in recent Liquid versions, the one running on Github (where my liquid is compiled) has 2.2.2, without ability to increment a counter. Toms solution itself is not working either, because Liquid turns the variable `counter` into a string, which cannot be compared with `<`.

I created a hack, by appending a string and counting the characters.

```
{% assign counter = '.' %}
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% if counter.size <= 25 and post.lang == "nl" %}
    {% capture counter %}{{ counter | append:'.' }}{% endcapture %}
    {% include li_for_post_with_date.yml %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

As said, ugly, so if there are cleaner solutions, please add a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can create the filtered collection without making a plugin or custom filter, but you may be able to count the number of posts already collected for the group rather than using limit.

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
    {% if counter < 25 and post.lang == nil or post.lang == "en" %}
        {% capture counter %}{{ counter | plus:1 }}{% endcapture %} 
        <li></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The code is untested, but something fairly similar should work.

Comment: Interesting direction. Capture, however, turns `counter` into a string, it cannot be compared to 25 after the first iteration :/. More recent "liquid" versions have "increment", but not the version that runs on Github.

Comment: Try some variations - comparing to the string "25" may work, or if plus wont add to the string you could use the length of the string rather than its value as the counter.

Comment: Yes, I am venturing in string-lenght. Where I simply concatenate a series of dots and compare that :).

Comment: @berkes Of course, `{% increment somevar %}`, unlike every other `{% %}` Liquid expression, is an output statement, so you'll have to capture (and stringify) it anyway. Liquid is truly a brutish, poorly-designed hack of a templating system. Even constructing a simple effective integer loop-counter will consume hours of time.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Liquid's filters dont't work in `for` loops. However, they do work in variable assignments.

```
{% assign posts_by_lang = site.posts | group_by: "lang" %}
{% for lang in posts_by_lang %}
  {{ lang.name }}
  {% for post in lang.items limit: 25 %}
    {{ post.title }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

`name` and `items` attributes are generated by `group_by`, the rest is business as usual.