# In Jekyll, how can I get all pages with a specific tag and limit the results to 3?

Tags: jekyll

In Jekyll, I want to create a homepage showing various categories of pages. For each category, I only want to show 5 pages. How can limit the page results to just 5 per category?

Here's the code I currently have for one of the category sections:

```
<ul>
{% for page in site.pages %}
{% for tag in page.tags %}
{% if tag == "news" %}
<li><a href="{{ page.permalink | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{page.title}}
</a></li>
<div class="summary">{{page.summary}}</div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>enter code here
```

If I add `limit:5` in the for page loop, it only looks at 5 pages -- it doesn't look at 5 pages with those tags:

```
<ul>
{% for page in site.pages limit:5 %}
{% for tag in page.tags %}
...
```

If I add `limit: 5` on the page.tags line, it doesn't do anything:

```
 <ul>
 {% for page in site.pages %}
 {% for tag in page.tags limit:5 %}
 ...
```

I want to avoid having one category that has a lot of pages from taking up too much space. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop **all pages**, and count how many with the right category you already found:

```
{% assign counter = '0' %}
{% for page in site.pages %}
{% for tag in page.tags %}
{% if tag == "news" and counter < '5' %}
    {% capture counter %}{{ counter | plus:'1' }}{% endcapture %}
<li><a href="{{ page.permalink | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{page.title}}
</a> ({{ counter }})</li>
<div class="summary">{{page.summary}}</div>

{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

*(tested with `site.posts` instead of `site.pages` on my blog, because I don't have a Jekyll project where the **pages** have tags/categories)*

The syntax to increase the variable looks a bit ugly, but apparently [increasing numeric variables in Liquid isn't that easy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13568052/6884) *(this was the first time I tried it myself)*.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I really appreciate your help. I'd been spinning my wheels on this issue for quite a while. This is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at `group_by`, which you can use with the `assign` tag.

```
<ul>
  {% assign authors = site.posts | group_by: "author" %}
  {% for author in authors %}
    <li>{{ author.name }}<ul>
      {% for page in author.items limit: 5 %}
        <li>{{ page.title }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```